# Conditional format with scale based on value AFTER passing through function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I got this far using "Format cells based on their values" and a 3-color scale.

[image]

The **Level mapped** column is mapping the values from the **Level** column using `XLOOKUP`. But I want to directly color the words in the **Level** column.

So, I don't want to "Format cells based on their values", I want to format based on their values after mapping them to new values based on a function. Is there a way to do this?

I know in this case I could create four separate rules that each use "Use a formula to determine which cells to format", but imagine a less minimal case where there are 50 different words, for example.

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what the expected end result should be?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I added a picture of expected result.